# Problema a compilar Gulp no Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, gulp, vue.js

Erro ao executar Gulp laravel 5.3, já reinstalei todos os pacotes.
O que fazer?
Segue o erro que me dá:

```
Vue packages version mismatch:
```

- vue@1.0.28
- vue-template-compiler@2.0.0-rc.8

This may cause things to work incorrectly. Make sure to use the same version for both.
If you are using vue-loader or vueify, re-installing them should bump vue-template-compiler to the latest.

Comment: Como está iniciando seu sistema? Utiliza composer? Tente utilizar o composer para gerenciar seus pacotes, ai poderá fazer um **laravel new nome_do_app**.

Comment: @Evert o que isso tem a ver com o problema? Ele está falando do `Gulp`, que é um processador de assets. O Laravel por padrão usa um chamado Elixir. Creio que esse seja o questionamento do AP.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters tá sumido rapaz! Que bom ter vc aqui pra corrigir e ajudar sempre! É que uma das versões do Laravel no git estava com o vue 2.0 que ainda está em lançamento, o que pode estar causando esse problema meu amigo. Provavelmente nosso amigo costinha clonou esse repositório. Isso é o que tem a ver com o questionamento. Posso estar errado mas esse foi o que entendi. Abraço

Comment: @Evert tô começando a achar que ele vai ter que postar pra gente como tá o `package.json` dele.

Comment: @costinha tente criar um novo projeto via composer e veja se o gulp funciona... daí verá que pode ser uma questão do versionamento do vue.

Comment: Peço ao Autor da Pergunta que acrescente os dados do `package.json` na pergunta, por gentileza.

Comment: Funcionou instalando pelo composer. Obrigado